# How to match a substring starting with one of several character sequences?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that could have any of these words

> Published By
>   Subjected By
>   By Teacher
>   For user

The terminator between the words is a period. So the complete string may look like this

```
var string = 'Publish By: John Rellin.  Subjected By: jj@test.com.';
```

or it could be like this

```
var string = 'Publish By: John Rellin.  Subjected By: jj@test.com. By Teacher: Jason Alexander';
```

or may be another variation

I am trying to see if there is any of those words in the string. If there is a `published by`, I want that in a match like `match[1]` which would be `Published By: John Rellin` etc

I am very new to regex and tried this

```
string.match(/(Published By:|Subjected By|By Teacher|For user)/);
```

but that didn't produce the results that I was hoping for.

I am not sure how would I achieve this. I read some documentations but was unable to find something that was close to what I am looking for.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

your string has "Publish By and your regex has "Publish**ED** By", which do not match